# How to adjust the keypoints from the images

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Can we extract keypoints from the background subtracted images ? i am extracting keypoint from the video by first subtracting its background , but it show me runtime error

```
    if (! previous_frame.empty())  {
       subtract(current_frame, previous_frame, predict_img);
       detector.detect(predict_img, keypoint2);
       if (keypoint2.size > 20) // Error
   {
       RetainBestKeypoints(keypoint2, 20);
   }
   else 
   {
       //Want to ignore the frame , but how ?
   }
```

Error's are mention in the code ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `detect()` method of keypoints detectors outputs an `std::vector` of keypoints. Thus, you should call `keypoint2.size()` instead of `size` without the parentheses.

Apart from that, and provoded that the type of the difference is compatible with the keypoint detector, yes you can (compute keypoints on difference images or background images).

Comment: `//Want to ignore the frame , but how ?` what should be used in else ?